# What does Error 000885: Input Signature file does not have file extension indicate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, classification

I can't run a Maximum Likelihood Classification because an [Error 000885](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp00000020000885) says my input signature file does not have a file extension but it actually does as you can see in the picture.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As troubleshot by @Paul, the error message is being triggered because you have placed your `*.gsg` file inside of a file geodatabase folder (`*.gdb`).

It seems like the [Maximum Likelihood Classification](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000pp000000) tool is getting confused by this.

However, the error can be easily avoided by ensuring that your `*.gsg` file is NOT inside of a file geodatabase folder (`*.gdb`).

There may be many other situations where the same or similar errors can be triggered so some advice offered here by @ChrisW etc is that although a file geodatabase (`*.gdb`) is a Windows folder it is unwise to store anything that is not part of a file geodatabase inside of its folder.